# Populating empty cells of a dataframe with nearest value of preceeding cell

Tags: python, pandas

Doing `res = ans.groupby(['Unique_Inventor_Number_x', 'AppYearStr_x']).Citation.nunique()` on a dataframe yields output as

```
Unique_Inventor_Number_x  AppYearStr_x
2.0                       1987.0           1
5.0                       1977.0           1
6.0                       1977.0           1
                          1987.0           1
                          1993.0           4
7.0                       1990.0           1
                          1994.0          10
                          1996.0           6
                          1998.0           6
                          1999.0           4
9.0                       1979.0           1
```

As seen, not all cells in `Unique_Inventor_Number_x` are populated. I want to populate all these cells with the preceeding integer as such:

```
Unique_Inventor_Number_x  AppYearStr_x
2.0                       1987.0           1
5.0                       1977.0           1
6.0                       1977.0           1
6.0                       1987.0           1
6.0                       1993.0           4
7.0                       1990.0           1
7.0                       1994.0          10
7.0                       1996.0           6
7.0                       1998.0           6
7.0                       1999.0           4
9.0                       1979.0           1
```

What is a quick way to do this in pandas?

Comment: did you try df.fillna(method = 'ffill')?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the the [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method with the kwarg `method='ffill'`. This will forward propagate forward for the empty values.

**Edit**
I see you are using a groupby and want to remove the empty values in the index. You could do this with:

```
res.reset_index().set_index('Unique_Inventor_Number_x')
```